# Identify anime that copied Bladerunner scene where Deckard was waiting for a noodle shop seat

Tags: story-identification

I never saw this anime to its completion, but I remember catching a scene where it was either parodying the Bladerunner scene where Deckard was waiting for a spot at the noodle shop. The anime character was dressed like deckard, and was holding a paper just like in the movie, while leaning against a shop's window with a neon sign.

Comment: This one? http://cdn8.laserbean.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/BladeRunner1080-2.jpg

Comment: yes, that scene. it may have been an anime short or a full feature. I don't know because I just saw that piece playing in a video shop.

Comment: Any chance  it is this bizarre "animation" of Blade Runner? https://youtu.be/SLwmlMezS3U?t=194

Comment: Or this fan made Blade Runner anime trailer? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lK0jsWnFGVY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the description at https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/feature/2017-10-06/blade-runner-unbelievable-influence-on-anime/.122391 this sounds like *Patlabor: The New Files* episode 10, "It's Called Amnesia":

> Mobile Police Patlabor is a far more optimistic view of the future than Blade Runner, so its influence isn't as clear-cut. But there was one extensive Blade Runner spoof sequence in the 10th OVA episode, “It's Called Amnesia” of what's released here as “The New Files.” Resident ill-tempered gun fanatic Ohta dreams of literally being Rick Deckard and wielding his trademark gun to “retire” those dastardly robots…who all happen to be his coworkers! Then, just like Deckard in Blade Runner, Ohta orders noodles in the rain and gets into an argument over the desired order quantity.